# Show that a set $A/{\sim}$ has the same cardinality as $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$ be sets. $f\,\colon A\rightarrow B$ is a surjective function. Define a relation $\sim$ in A by:

for every $x$, $y\in A$, $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$

(a) Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

(b) Show that $A/{\sim}$ has the same cardinality as $B$.

I have finished (a) but do not know how to start with part (b). What does $A/{\sim}$ mean? Does it mean that exclude the elements satisfying $\sim$ and in set $A$?

Comment: $A /  \sim$ is the set of [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class).

Comment: I think the quiestion in (b) implies that the function is also injective as we exclude all the element in A with ~ . Then it is bijective. But how should I write down such deduction

Comment: Thanks! I should now study the stuff related to equivalence classes first.

Comment: @DietrichBurde and Rot Civ : When you write $x\sim y$, the symbol $\sim$ has the amount of spacing before and after it that is appropriate to binary relation symbols, and that's why you see an inappropriate amount of space in the expression $A/\sim$.  The remedy is to code that as A/{\sim}, with {curly braces} around that symbol so that nothing appears to its left or right.  Then it looks like this: $A/{\sim}\,. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\pi\colon A\to A/{\sim}$ be the canonical projection. Show that $\tilde{f}\colon A/{\sim}\to B$ defined by the relation $\tilde{f}\circ\pi=f$ is bijective.

Comment: Notice this difference: $$ A/\sim \qquad \text{versus} \qquad A/{\sim} $$ They look different for a reason.  See my comment under the question.  I edited the answer accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy, I was wondering how to display this quotient set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't posted an answer here because Dietrich Burde already posted the answer in a comment, but some hours have passed and he hasn't made it into an answer.

$A/{\sim}$ is the set of equivalence classes.

For eample, suppose $A=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $a,b,c$ are equivalent to each other, and $d,e$ are equivalent to each other but not to $a$ or $b$ or $c$.  Thus
$$
a\sim b\sim c \quad \text{and}\quad d\sim e.
$$
Then $A/{\sim}$ has two members:
$$
A/{\sim} = \big\{\  \{a,b,c\},\  \{d,e\}\  \big\}.
$$
It is as if we are regarding $a,b,c$ as being just one thing rather than three, and that one thing is one member of $A/{\sim}$ and there is one other member, called either $d$ or $e$.

Or one could say that $a,b,c$ are *different in their roles as members of $A$*, but are *the same as each other in their roles as members of $A/{\sim}$*.